# Find all embedded documents from manual reference in MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, mongotemplate

I use MongoDB and Spring Boot in a project. I used manual reference to point out a collection, My structure is as follows:

**Reel collection**

```
{
    _id : "reel_id_1",
    name: "reel 1",
    category :[
        {
            _id : "category_id_1",
            name: "category 1", 
            videos: ["video_id_1","video_id_2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Video collection**

```
{
    _id: "video_id_1",  // first document
    name: "mongo"
}

{
    _id: "video_id_2",  // seconddocument
    name: "java"
}
```

Java classes are

```
@Document
@Data
public class Reel {

    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private String name;

    List<Category> category;
}

@Data
public class Category {

    @Id    
    private ObjectId _id=new ObjectId();
    private String name;

    Video videos;
}

@Document
@Data
public class Video {

    @Id
    private ObjectId _id = new ObjectId();
    private String name;
    
}
```

I tried to join both document via mongoTemplate

```
public List<Reel> findById(ObjectId _id) {
    LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("video")
            .localField("category.videos")
            .foreignField("_id")
            .as("category.videos");


    UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("category");
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(unwindOperation,match(Criteria.where("_id").is(_id)),lookupOperation);


    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(lookupOperation);
    List<Reel> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "reel", Reel.class).getMappedResults();
    return results;
}
```

But it throws an error.

```
Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
```

But since I use "unwind", I created a new Entity **UnwindReel** and add `Category category` instead of `List<Category> category`. And used

`List<UnwindReel> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "reel", UnwindReel.class).getMappedResults();`

It combines only first video (video_id_1) object. How can I get all objects inside **videos array**? Is there any method to fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON stored in database has wrong structure. Your `Reel` class expects list of `Category`, but in database you have stored as nested object.

You need to add this stage just after `$lookup`

```
{
  "$addFields": {
    "category": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$category.videos",
        "in": {
          "videos": "$$this"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Java code

```
public List<Reel> findById(String _id) {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(_id)),
            Aggregation.lookup(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Video.class), "category.videos", "_id", "category.videos"),
            new AggregationOperation() {

                @Override
                public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                    return new Document("$addFields",
                            new Document("category", new Document("$map", new Document("input", "$category.videos")
                                    .append("in", new Document("videos", "$$this")))));
                }
            })
        .withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    LOG.debug(
            aggregation.toString().replaceAll("__collection__", mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Reel.class)));

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Reel.class), Reel.class)
            .getMappedResults();

}
```

### Recomendations

1. Do not hard-code collection name, use better `mongoTemplate.getCollectionName` method
2. Always log aggregation pipeline before performing, it helps debugging.
3. If your collection will grow in the future, use `{allowDiskUse: true}` MongoDb aggregation option.

Comment: Thank god, you saved me sir. I'm newbie to mongoBD. But I have two queries,  you mentioned that the database structure is wrong. But I saved category as array of objects in Reel.class, may i know what's wrong with it? If i change `List<Video>` instead of `Video` in Category collection, how can i change the above query.

Comment: If i change `List<Video>` instead of `Video` in Category collection, I'd like to sore some additional properties like `catgeory:[ videos:[{_id: "vid_1",upvote:6,downvote: 10 },{_id: "vid_2",upvote:3,downvote: 7 }]]`. How can i change the above query.

Comment: @Nishakar update your answer please, so I could add sample code

Comment: @Valijon may I know whats wrong with the structure as you mentioned which helps me not to implement wrong design