# MongoDB Lookup Aggregation that better uses $map operator

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have Parking collection like:

```
parking: {
   _id: xxxxxx,
   name: xxxxxx,
   vehicles: [{vehicleId: xxxxx, bid: xxxxx}...]
}
```

and car collection:

```
car: {
  _id: "xxxx",
  attributes: [xxxxx],
  color: "xxxx"
}
```

When I do **Lookup Aggregation**:

```
  $lookup: {
     from: "car",
     localField: "vehicles.vehicleId",
     foreignField: "_id",  
     as: "cars"
  }
```

I get:

```
parking: {
   _id: xxxxxx,
   name: xxxxxx,
   vehicles: [{vehicleId: xxxxx, bid: xxxxx}],
   cars: [car1,car2...]
}
```

So I struggle with merging new cars array with objects in vehicles array that match id.
Can I somehow replace vehicleId with car document that match?

I tried this but group operation remove name field from parking

```
 db.parking.aggregate([
 { "$unwind": "$vehicles" },
 { "$lookup": {
   "from": "car",
   "as": "vehicles.vehicle",
   "localField": "vehicles.vehicleId",
   "foreignField": "_id"
 }},
 { "$unwind": "$vehicles.vehicle" },
 { "$group": {
   "_id": "$_id",
   "vehicles": { "$push": "$vehicles" }
 }}
 ])
```

Comment: can you post please sample data for cars collection?

Comment: @Valijon I update , basicaly I need entire car to be instead vehicleId for each object in vehicles field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier use `$map` operator by combining the `$reduce` operator.

Try this one:

```
db.parking.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "car",
      "localField": "vehicles.vehicleId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "cars"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      vehicles: {
        $map: {
          input: "$vehicles",
          as: "veh",
          in: {
            bid: "$$veh.bid",
            vehicleId: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$cars",
                initialValue: "$$veh.vehicleId",
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$$veh.vehicleId" ]
                    },
                    "$$this",
                    "$$value"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      cars: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/krrNx-lUEBC) | [Replace vehicleId](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gCdnqqycekr)

Comment: Thank you I tried figured out two paths for this but cannot get to work projection in Spring...Aggregation.project().and("vehicles").nested(Fields.fields("vehicles.vehicle._color")) give me error that cannot use dotted field in sub-obj?

Comment: or when use Aggregation.project("vehicles.vehicle._id"); gives me null

Comment: @UrosKalajdzic Spring data ProjectAggregation is hard to populate, try "ugly" manual implementation with [$addFields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166172/3710490)

Comment: Thanks again, looks like project take less operations than addFields do you know maybe what are performance losses between them if I use addFields?

Comment: In mongodShell {$project: {"vehicles.vehicle._id": 1, "vehicles.vehicle.color": 1}} works good but Spring Api cannot get it write

Comment: @UrosKalajdzic `$addFields` doesn't affect performance. As I said, Spring `ProjectAggregation` is low usability (too much mental wank to write correct expression), it's better implement `toDocument` and pass directly JSON document.